# How do you use left join's instead of group by?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have to take code similar to this:

```
SELECT courseId, termId, firstName, lastName
FROM (
   SELECT s.courseId, s.termId, t.teacherId
   FROM Teaches t, Section s
   WHERE s.id = t.sectionId
   GROUP BY s.termId, s.courseId
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.teacherId) = 1
) Teach, Person p
WHERE p.id = teacherId
ORDER BY courseId, termId;
```

and turn it into a MySql statement with 1 subquery, no group by's and no aggregate functions using only joins (inner joins, left joins, etc.). I've been trying for hours but I cant figure out a way to group without using the group by function. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In order to help you we need to understand 1) the structure of these three tables, and 2) what kind of result set you expect to get.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this returns an equivalent resultset, using only JOIN and only one subquery. (I haven't tested.)

My general approach to solving the puzzle is to make use of the one subquery that is allowed, and to use a NOT EXISTS predicate to test for the existence of a "matching" row.

```
 SELECT s.courseId
      , s.termId
      , p.firstName
      , p.lastName
   FROM Section s
   JOIN Teaches t
     ON t.sectionID = s.id
   LEFT
   JOIN Person p
     ON p.id = t.teacherId
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT 1
            FROM Section c
            JOIN Teaches d
              ON d.sectionId = c.id
           WHERE c.courseId   = s.courseId   -- match (as equivalent to group by)
             AND c.termId     = s.termID     -- match (as equivalent to group by)
             AND c.id        <> s.id         -- but not the same row (count=1)
             AND d.teacherId <> t.teacherId  -- but not the same row (count=1)
        )
  ORDER
     BY s.courseId
      , s.termId
```

The correlated subquery in the NOT EXISTS predicate is looking for a matching row, but of course, the row itself would match, so we need to exclude it.

I may not have an understanding of which columns are in which tables, so what I have may not work.  (Qualifying ALL column references in a query is a both 1) an aid to the reader, that may not know which columns are in which tables, and 2) avoiding the query inadvertently being "broken" with an "ambiguous column" exception, when a column of the same name is added to one of the tables involved in the query.

I've made some assumptions about uniqueness of the `id` column in Section and the `teacherId` column in Teaches.

(The fact that Section and Teaches are joined makes it a little uglier, it would be easier to see if it were a single table.)

```
SELECT t
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
       ( SELECT 1
           FROM mytable d
          WHERE d.somecol = t.somecol -- a match!
            AND d.id     <> t.id      -- not the same row!
       )
```

I actually think this can be solved with an anti-join pattern, without using any subquery at all, but the three tables joined together (Section, Teach and Person) are making it difficult for me to wrap my brain around that.

Comment: I actually don't see how the original sub query works as the selected column teacher_id is not in group by column.